# OpenSSL undefined symbol: undefined symbol: Camellia_set_key, version OPENSSL_1_1_0

Tags: linux, openssl, centos, rhel8

I have the following issue when trying to check OpenSSL:

`openssl: symbol lookup error: openssl: undefined symbol: Camellia_set_key, version OPENSSL_1_1_0`

There also seem to be issues with yum, rpm if I try to uninstall/install anything on the machine.
Trying yum I get this:

`ImportError: /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3: undefined symbol: Camellia_cbc_encrypt, version OPENSSL_1_1_0`

Trying rpm I get this:

`rpm: symbol lookup error: /lib64/librpmio.so.8: undefined symbol: EVP_md2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0`

Trying to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.1.1g fails as stated https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11856 fails.

Running `sudo ldconfig` gives this:
`sudo: unable to load /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so: /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3: undefined symbol: Camellia_cbc_encrypt, version OPENSSL_1_1_0 sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins`

This started happening after installing a package that requested install of these packages: glibc-2.28-164.el8.i686, libgcc-8.5.0-4.el8_5.i686, libstdc++-8.5.0-4.el8_5.i686.
Linux version is RHEL 8.5. The same packages were installed on version 7 and worked well.

Comment: Camellia is a cipher that is included in recent versions of openssl. libk5crypto is the Kerberos library, which expects to be installed with a compatible openssl version. Yours appear to be out of sync.

Comment: Same thin happening in Ubuntu System. But ldconfig wuns without giving any error or log.